# how can I highlight ui grid row, if one of the columns has a specific value

Tags: angularjs, ui-grid

I have a ui grid which one its columns is 'status'.

I want that if a row contains column 'status' that equals to 'pending' it will highlight the row in green.

I gone through many threads here and havent been able to make it work yet.

I tried to do something like that:

```
gridOptions.rowTemplate = generateRowTemplate();

function generateRowTemplate() {
            return '  <div ng-if="row.entity.status == \'pending\'" style=\'color: #26b72b;\'> </div>';
        }
```

but that way the grid isn't generated at all.
is **row.entity.status** the correct way of retrieving 'status' column value?

In addition, I probably override the whole row template which isn't good.

What is the correct way of doing so?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to solve this with an `ng-class` directive on your row rather than using an ng-if and a inline style.

```
$scope.gridOptions.rowTemplate = '<div ng-class="{ 'green': row.entity.status === 'pending'}"></div>';
```

But your current code has a problem is a think the way you scape the quotes characters, according to the [docs](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions) this is no needed:

```
return '<div ng-if="row.entity.status === 'pending'" style="color: #26b72b;"></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fine to replace the rowTemplate, but you need to use the base template:

```html
`<div 
  ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" 
  ui-grid-one-bind-id-grid="rowRenderIndex + '-' + col.uid + '-cell'" 
  class="ui-grid-cell" 
  ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }" 
  role="{{col.isRowHeader ? 'rowheader' : 'gridcell'}}" 
  ui-grid-cell>
</div>`
```

I would do it like this:

```
gridOptions.rowTemplate = `
<div 
  ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" 
  ui-grid-one-bind-id-grid="rowRenderIndex + '-' + col.uid + '-cell'" 
  class="ui-grid-cell" 
  ng-class="{
    'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader,
    'my-highlight-class': row.entity.status === 'pending'
  }" 
  role="{{col.isRowHeader ? 'rowheader' : 'gridcell'}}" 
  ui-grid-cell>
</div>`
```

Notice that I included one condition in the ng-class directive:

```
'my-highlight-class': row.entity.status === 'pending'
```

And answering your other question: Yes, "row.entity.columnName" is one way to get the value.